# How to create trigger on metadata to detect autoreplies?

Tags: apex, metadata

I've been tasked with the responsibility of creating a trigger to detect autoreply emails for cases created in salesforce. To do this, I have created a custom metadata object that multiple records of special words that can indicate an autoreply. Can someone tell me if my code is functioning properly, by adding the metadata records to a string set, then comparing the email string to the set? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction, thanks.

```
private static void detectAutoresponse(){
    Autoresponse_Blacklist_mdt[] errorRecords = [SELECT MasterLabel, Body_Text_c 
                                                  from Autoresponse_Blacklist_mdt];
    Set<String> errorWords = new Set<String>;
    for(Autoresponse_Blacklist_mdt record: errorRecords){
        errorWords.add(record.Body_Text_c);
    }

    for(Case thisCase : (List<Case>)Trigger.new){
        for(Sting words: errorWords){
            if(thisCase.Contain == words)
                thisCase.addError('Not saving Automatic Reply');
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. As it stands, the above code won't compile and you need to fix those errors first.

Comment: You need to tell us if your code is working properly.